# list navigation that slides open to left to open, slides right to close

Tags: jquery, html

I have currently a simple list navigation that the user clicks on and the nav slides down and slides up to close. I was wondering if there is a way for the nav list to slide to the left to open and then slide right to close the list nav. Using my current jquery code can I modify it have the list nav slide to the left to open and then slide right to close. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!  Here is my current code and link to my js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jsavage/eGAYt/

here's my jquery code.

```
$(function(){
 var $menuContent = $(".list-menu, .list-menu-registration");
 $("#menu-list-btn").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   if($menuContent.hasClass('opened')){
    $menuContent.slideUp('slow').toggleClass('closed opened');
  } else {
    $menuContent.slideDown('slow').toggleClass('closed opened');
  }
 });
 });
```

Comment: [This was my quick 5 minute rendition](http://jsfiddle.net/QmEcs/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use animation and margin to slide in from right to left.

```
.drop-down-nav {
    float: left;
    width: 640px; 
    height: 159px;
    background-color:grey;  
    padding: 1px 0;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:600px;
    clear: both;

}
```

jquery:

```
var $itemContent = $('.drop-down-nav');
$('.drop-down-btn-up, .drop-down-btn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    if($itemContent.css('margin-left') == "600px"){
         $('.drop-down-nav').animate({
                  marginLeft: '0px',
                  opacity:1
              })

    } else {
         $('.drop-down-nav').animate({
                  marginLeft: '600px',
                  opacity:0
              });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QmEcs/8/

Comment: max li - I've just updated my fiddle .... please take a look and any help would be greatly appreciate